# Por que o parseInt retorna NaN?

Tags: javascript, html

eu estou com este código:

```js
function aparecer() {
  const elemento1 = document.getElementById('numero').value;
  const elemento2 = parseInt(elemento1);

  alert(elemento2)
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onClick="aparecer()"> Aparecer </button>
  <button onClick="desaparecer()"> Desaparecer </button>
  <p id="numero">0 </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Porém ele está retornando NaN. Por que? Se o parseInt retorna ele como numeral ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe o atributo `VALUE`então logo a função não vai encontrar, olhe no console (Tecla F12) para ver o erro que causa.

Substitua por `innerHTML`:

```
function aparecer() {
  const elemento1 = document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML;
  const elemento2 = parseInt(elemento1);

  alert(elemento2);
}
```

Sempre use ponto e vírgula após o fim de cada função chamada ou variável.

Comment: `value` existe, porém somente nos elementos que estendem de [**HTMLInputElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) e alguns outros elementos do `<form>`

Comment: Eu quis dizer no caso a TAG `<p>` em si não possuía o atributo `VALUE` então logo não existe para os elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Muito melhor você pegar o valor com `textContent` em vez de `innerHTML`. Isso porque se você resolver depois adicionar alguma outra tag no HTML do elemento, irá novamente retornar **NaN**.

Exemplos com `innerHTML`:

```
 ✓ OK! IRÁ RETORNAR 0
<p id="numero">0</p>
parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML);

 X ERRO! IRÁ RETORNAR NaN
<p id="numero"><b>0</b></p>
parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML);
```

**Teste:**

```js
function aparecer() {
  const elemento1 = document.getElementById('numero').innerHTML;
  const elemento2 = parseInt(elemento1);

  alert(elemento2)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="aparecer()"> Aparecer </button>
<button onClick="desaparecer()"> Desaparecer </button>
<p id="numero"><b>0</b> </p>
```

Exemplos com `textContent`:

```
 ✓ OK! IRÁ RETORNAR 0
<p id="numero">0</p>
parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').textContent);

 ✓ OK! IRÁ RETORNAR 0
<p id="numero"><b>0</b></p>
parseInt(document.getElementById('numero').textContent);
```

**Teste:**

```js
function aparecer() {
  const elemento1 = document.getElementById('numero').textContent;
  const elemento2 = parseInt(elemento1);

  alert(elemento2)
}
```

```html
<button onClick="aparecer()"> Aparecer </button>
<button onClick="desaparecer()"> Desaparecer </button>
<p id="numero"><b>0</b> </p>
```

O `innerHTML` tem função de gerir código HTML e não para pegar texto ou valores em forma de texto.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function aparecer() {
  var elemento1 = document.getElementById("numero").getAttribute("value");
  var elemento2 = parseInt(elemento1);

  alert(elemento2);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onClick="aparecer()"> Aparecer </button>
  <button onClick="desaparecer()"> Desaparecer </button>
  <p id="numero" value="0">0</p>
</body>

</html>
```